# sql query to find datatypes in teradata

Tags: teradata

I've never dealt with Teradata database before, I need to find out the data types for a table in Teradata I tried the below queries but none of them worked

```
describe table tablename; show create table tablename;help table tablename;
```

When I did show table I realized that it is a view and I tried 
`show view view name; 
help view view name;`

none of the above queries gave me the datatypes for the view I'm looking to find out. i googled around and tried my findings none of them worked.

Please help me with the query to find out the data types in teradata.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Manual https://developer.teradata.com/sites/all/files/documentation/linked_docs/2414020A_BTEQ-Reference-13.10.pdf should be in there somewhere good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HELP COLUMN mytable.*;` resolves views and returns the actual datatypes.

The description of the two character `ColumnType` can be found in the [Data Dictionary manual](http://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1092_151K/Views_Reference.018.133.html)

Answer (score 1):

The stuff people have already said is great if you need the whole table.  However, if you just need 1 specific field and want the result to be readable (without having to dig around in the data dictionary manual), sometimes I find it simpler to just do something like:

```
Select Distinct TYPE(Fieldname)
from mytable
```

For many reasons, this isn't the solution you want to use every time but I think it is worth adding to what people have already said.

Comment: This will result in a Full Table Scan and a Distinct operation, better use `select type(mytable.Fieldname)` instead.

Comment: Thanks you! Finally a solution that works in views with hidden source tables